# Keras custom loss with external data

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

Hello? I'm trying to write custom loss function with external data.

My code is like that:

```
classes_distributions = K.variable(np.full((A, A), 1.0 / A, dtype=float))

def my_loss(distributions):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        x = math_ops.argmax(y_pred, axis=0)
        for i in range(A):
            classes_slice = distributions[x[i], :]
            _class = math_ops.add(classes_slice, K.flatten(y_true[:, i]))
            _class = math_ops.multiply(_class, 1.0 / K.sum(_class))
            classes_slice.assign(_class)
        # Mean enthropy of classes.
        log_p = math_ops.log(distributions)
        H = - math_ops.multiply(distributions, log_p)
        H = K.sum(H, axis=1)
        H = K.mean(H)
        return tf.fill((A,), H)
    return loss

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=A*10, input_shape=(A, 1)))
model.add(Dense(units=A, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=my_loss(classes_distributions))
history = model.fit(
    data, 
    data, # The main idea is using loss-function only
    epochs=200,
    verbose=True, 
    batch_size=A)
```

But I have error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

...

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['lstm_69/lstm_cell_69/kernel:0', 'lstm_69/lstm_cell_69/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_69/lstm_cell_69/bias:0', 'dense_69/kernel:0', 'dense_69/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, )).
```

I understand, that problem in `return tf.fill((A,), H)`, but have no idea, where is mistake.

Maybe it is some dimentional problem, because if i replace
`return tf.fill((A,), H)`
with
`return K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)` (from tensorflow sample code), it's OK.

But

```
tf.print(tf.shape(K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)))
tf.print(tf.shape(tf.fill((A,), H)))
```

returns

```
[35]
[35]
```

And this is the same shape!

Comment: Your loss is not using y_true or y_pred, specially not using y_pred does not make much sense, that is why there are no gradients.

Comment: I don't know output data. But I know some distribution parameters.  Here y_true is input data.

Comment: I use y_true and y_pred in `# ... here is some changes in distributions (it works)` place/

Comment: Then actually show the code in comments, do not leave it out for people to guess.

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: argmax is not differentiable

Comment: But my loss values are enthropies now. And enthropy is differentiable.

Comment: It is only differentiable if its connected to y_pred, what exactly is this loss supposed to do?

Comment: It minimies entropies in classes.

Comment: I would not agree, the cross-entropy does that, this loss will never work like this, as I said, it does not consider the model predictions (y_pred).

Comment: Maybe, but the shape of output is correct. how can I connect it to y_pred?

Comment: use y_pred in your loss in a way that influences the output values of the loss. What is even the need for external variables?

Comment: External variable is tensor of distributions (equiprobable at start). Then I want to fill classes by vectors to minimize some measure (maybe not only enthropy, but it wil be in future).

Comment: Thank's it works now (compilable =) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's to Dr. Snoopy in comments.

```
O = tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_pred))
O = math_ops.multiply(O, y_pred)
O = math_ops.add(O, distributions)
log_p = math_ops.log(O)
H = - math_ops.multiply(O, log_p)
H = K.sum(H, axis=1)
H = K.mean(H)
return tf.fill((A,), H)
```

solves my problem.

Funny, because it is multiplying by zero and adding the answer for connecting y_pred with output.

And

```
O = math_ops.multiply(tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_pred)), y_pred)
O = K.mean(O)
# Some math with scalar-tensor output loss.
return loss + O  # Corret here for batch_size = tf.shape(y_pred)[0]
```

also works.